# How to make sure that no one reads from Ehcache Object, while data is being written into the cache?

Tags: caching, ehcache-bigmemory, ehcache-3

I want to store data into the Cache using **EhCache**, but if I try to access the data before data has been populated into the Cache, I get **NULL POINTER exception**. How can I make sure that Data is not read from the cache until and unless data has been stored into the Cache?

Answer (score 2):

What you are requesting will make cache usage very problematic.

If you always block on a missing entry, any eviction or expiry will put you in the same situation as having an empty cache / missing mapping.

However, using *cache-through* might be a better way to look at the problem. It would leave the loading of the mapping to the cache itself making sure you never get a `null` result (unless that key does not exist in the backing store).

See [documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/caching-patterns.html#cache-through) for more information on that option.