# How to synchronize action of multiple threads in EhCache?

Tags: java, concurrency, ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory, ehcache-3

How to synchronize the action of multiple threads and make sure that only one thread can access the resource at a given point in time in `EhCache`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question but let's guess. EhCache (3, I don't know about 2) is fully thread-safe.

However, if you really mean that one entry can be used by only one thread at the time, that's not something EhCache will do as this is a specific need. You need to put your own synchronisation on top of it. Using a lock or a semaphore. For example, you could lock on the retrieved value.

Comment: My issue was when we start two or more threads within a program, there may be a situation when multiple threads try to access the same resource stored in EhCache and finally they can produce unforeseen result due to concurrency issues. So, to avoid this, I have to write my own synchronization code.

Comment: They can retrieve the entry without any issues. But of course, if they start modifying the entry, you indeed need synchronization. Ehcache can't do anything for you there.

Comment: I added my own synchronization code..but I faced the following issue-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834377/can-same-ehcache-object-of-same-cache-manager-be-used-by-multiple-threads

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is close to another one of yours and cache-through could help you.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45801562/18591