# Can same Ehcache object of same CacheManager be used by multiple threads?

Tags: java, concurrency, ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory, ehcache-3

I have created a `Cache` object which stores a `String` as the key and a serialized object as the value.

```
Cache(String--->Object)
```

I am trying to run three Akka threads which retrieve and write into the same Ehcache object in a synchronized way.

```
Thread 1- synchronized (LockForEhcache){ 
              serializedObj = cachename.get("key"); //--- this returns an Object            
          }
          //modify the serializedObj here....
          //Again store the modify Object in the Cache
          synchronized (LockForEhcache){
              cachename.clear();
              cachename.put("key",serializedObj);
Thread 2- synchronized (LockForEhcache){ 
              serializedObj = cachename.get("key"); //--- this returns null
          }
Thread 3- synchronized (LockForEhcache){ 
              serializedObj = cachename.get("key"); //--- this returns null
          }
```

But only one thread gets the value stored in the `Cache`. For the rest of the threads, it throws a `NullPointerException`. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Not sure what these `synchronized (LockForEhcache)` are about... but ehcache doesn't require you to synchronize accesses, it's entirely thread safe to use... If, on the other hand, you're trying to synchronize these threads so that thread 1 has put, before t2 & t3 get to `get`, this won't work as is. Or is it just to say you've done something?

Comment: I am using locks so that no other  thread tries  to **get**  unless thread 1 completes its **put** . Why would this not work?

Comment: Well, maybe I'm "guessing" too much here... Is t1 the main thread and t2 & t3 are spun off from that? If not, and all three threads are racing to acquire the lock, then this _might_ work, but nondeterministically (i.e. you have no guarantees t1 grabs the lock first and installs the mapping).
If t1 spawns off the two other threads, it'd still need to do so _after_ having installed the mapping. The lock only provides exclusion, not ordering.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a cache is not a store. So you can't expect a cache to return the latest data all the time. For different reasons, it might return null.

Right now, unless some eviction or expiration occurs, the data should be there. So I will need a full example to tell you what's going on.

My first question would be: Why do you clear and put? Why not only put? And do we agree that clear will clear all entries? You only have one entry in your cache?

Comment: Here, clear will remove all the entries stored in the Cache and store the latest ones. Thus, every time only one entry will be present in the Cache.

Comment: Why not just overwriting them? And you need this to be atomic? (the full replace synchronized)

Comment: I removed the synchronized block and now it works without any null pointer exception. But, how can I make sure that **get** is not called by other Threads, when **put** is going on by Thread 1?

Comment: I don't think you care. Ehcache will take care of that. There is a before and a after the put. So the new value isn't visible to anyone and then it is visible to everyone. Adding higher synchronization will only broader the lock.

Comment: If removing the synchronized block is all you did, the code snippet above can't be complete. And most probably your code is still racy in some way...
That being said, do you _really_ care? What is this code even trying to prove/do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm only seeing now that the first thread also starts with a `get`, so does that mean that the mapping is installed *always*? If so, are you sure the other threads are actually using the same `Cache` instance?

Comment: Yes, all the threads are using the same **Cache instance**. Can you elaborate more on what do you  mean by mapping is installed?
Does it mean that once I do a **get** from **Cache**, all the updates I do on that serialized object will be stored in Cache without using **put**?

Comment: If you store the (immutable) serialized form, then no. Nothing will be updated automagically. If, on the other hand, you store the actual mutable object, then... it depends: as long as the reference is on-heap (i.e. it depends on your cache's topology and possibly timing) then any changes to the object _may_ become visible to other threads, according to the JMM. The `put` will introduce a happens-before relationship with the `get` for that key.

Comment: What happens if the reference is on-disk?